# How to convert Blender models for XNA

Tags: xna, models, blender

I am creating my first game, I'm using Blender to create character models, is there any tutorial or guide to tell me what steps to convert a model into something animated and usable in XNA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export Blender 2.59 models with animations to XNA 4](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17660/export-blender-2-59-models-with-animations-to-xna-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Blender 2.5 (maybe 2.5x) can export fbx models which are used in XNA. It even has an "XNA strict options" check. I noticed that it tends to export the models a bit small so you may want to set the scale to 100 or so but otherwise it is good to go.

Comment: This is the same answer provided in my duplicate...

Comment: yes and even though i didnt look at that I just made it a little quicker :P

Comment: Why didn't you look at it? I marked it as a duplicate hours before your answer.

Comment: well i knew what it said :)